# State of the Mean Value theorem for inetgrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am getting confused by the Mean value theorem for integrals, differently stated in different sources.  The idea is that for any continuous functions $f$ on ana  interval $[a,b]$, there exists some $c$ such taht  $$ \int_a^b f(x)dx =f(c)(b-a) $$
**My question is: should  $c$  be in $(a,b) $ or  $[a,b]$ ?**

In [Wikipédia](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Integrals)
 it is stated with $c$ in the closed interval, however in the proof, where they used the Intermediate value theorem, they took $c$ in the open inetrval.

Could  someone clarify it for me ?

Comment: $c\in (a,b)$. $ \ \ \ $

Comment: Strictly speaking, they only get $\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f \in [f(m),f(M)]$, which does not allow them to apply their stated version of the intermediate value theorem, which needs $\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf \in (f(m),f(M))$. But if its is equal to $f(m)$ or $f(M)$, you can show that $f$ is actually a constant on $[a,b]$, so it doesn't matter

Comment: Let $F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ then applying usual mean value theorem on $F$ shows that $c\in(a, b) $ works fine.